# Why is there a base64 link after pulling .attr('src')? - jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, image, woocommerce, base64

Here is part of the script I am using to pull images from the products list on my WooCommerce website to use in a custom lightbox.

```
   var index = 0;
        jQuery('.et_shop_image').each(function(){

            var img = jQuery(this).find('img');
            var src = img.attr('src');
            index = index + 1;

            jQuery(this).after('<a href="#"><span class="shopMfg dashicons dashicons-search" id="shopmfg' + index + '"></span></a>');
            jQuery('body').after('<div class="prodLightbox shopmfg' + index + '" style="display:none;"><image src="' + src + '" alt="product-image"></image><span class="lbClose"></span></div>');

        });
```

Pretty basic, just pulling the image url from the `src` attribute for each product. HOWEVER, the caching plugin I am using (WP Rocket) is lazy loading my images and for some reason I am getting a `base64` encoded link in the `src` attribute instead of the normal one. This results in no image shown in my lightbox. I've already tried wrapping the script in a `jQuery(document).ready()` function and still no change.

I'm pretty sure the WHY is because of the lazy loading, but I don't know how to resolve this.

Here is an example of the returned html

```
   <div class="prodLightbox shopmfg1" style="display: inline-block;">
        <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=" alt="product-image">
        <span class="lbClose"></span>
   </div>
```

Comment: Can you post an example base64 encode string that you are getting?

Comment: @ShekharChikara Sure, I updated the question with the output example.

Comment: The `img` tag you posted is a WP Rocket default placeholder image. That placeholder is filtered by the `rocket_lazyload_placeholder` filter. So the question is, why are you getting a placeholder image instead of the actual product image? is your lazy load failing? Any errors in console?

Comment: @Spartacus on page load its evident that lazy load is definitely working. And since activation of lazy load, loading times were pretty heavily impacted. However there are two POST 500 errors coming from  admin-ajax in console that do not occur on the localhost version of the site which doesn't have WP Rocket activated.